# Is the a wifi monitor app for iOS that can be remotely accessed to retrieve results?

Tags: ios, wifi

we are field trialing a vehicle mounted wifi router for use by clients with ipads who go out and visit places, taking their WiFi with them.

A common complaint from users is "slow Wifi", but of course by the time the complaint reaches us the details of exactly what was slow, and where, have been lost.

Does anyone know of an iOS app that could be installed to capture (or, ideally. send back ) a report of wifi conditions ( RSSI, possibly "internet speed" ) either in the background or when a user invokes it. This might enable us to make some sense of what conditions are like in the field.

Any suggestions appreciated. Unfortunately we cannot change the client systems to something more open, and don't manage the client devices, so I'm looking to see if anyone knows of an app that we could simply request to be installed to monitor things for us with minimal friction to users and their IT team.

Many thanks.